# Regex: multiline, whitespace only until certain character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using https://www.debuggex.com/ to visualize and aid in development of my RegEx strings.
Node.js is the target platform I'll be executing the regex in.

I'm looking to find the first instance of a certain character, let's say `{` (open brace).
This character may be prefixed with zero or more whitespace characters, such as:

```
'  \t\t \n\n {'
'  {'
'{'
```

but may not be prefixed with any non-whitespace, so f.ex. these should not match:

```
'\n\n\t  u  {'
'  r   {'
'${'
```

using this regex: `/\s*{/gmi` simply skips past the non-whitespace characters.
I've tried limiting with these methods:

- `/[^\S]\s*{/gmi`  <-- 'none of whitespace characters'..this still matches
- `/(\S{,0})\s*{/gmi` <-- this doesn't match anything?

I'm using `.lastIndex` property of the regex object for custom offsets in the string.  The behaviour I'm looking for for will return null in cases where there are non-whitespace characters before my special character, and will return a match when there are only zero or more whitespace before my special.

Comment: You’re just missing the line begin anchor `^` in your regex: `/^\s*{/gmi`.

Comment: no that fails when .lastIndex != 0

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: > s='\n bad \t{}'
'\n bad \t{}'
> r=/^\s*{/gmi
/^\s*{/gim
> r.lastIndex = 5 // start after 'bad'
5
> r.exec(s)
null

Please try before suggesting next time

Comment: I think want you're looking for is a negative lookbehind. Unfortunately these are not available in the Javascript Regex engine. If your curious though, you can try `(?<!\S)\s*{` in Debuggex using either the Python or the PCRE engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johnny Estilles wrote:
I think want you're looking for is a negative lookbehind. Unfortunately these are not available in the Javascript Regex engine. If your curious though, you can try (?

so the answer is:

```
currently there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve the desired behaviour using a single regex (JavaScript regex engine)
```

the primary factors contributing to this seem to be:

```
• use of regex 'start of string' ^ does not work when .lastIndex != 0
• negative lookbehinds not supported by JavaScript
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to do this, but here's one:

```
/^\s*$/.test(str.slice(0, bracket_pos, str.search(/\{/)))
```

In English: is the substring from the beginning of the string to the location of the left curly brackets composed solely of zero or more whitespace characters?

Or, you could split on the `{`:

```
/^\s*$/.test(str.split('{')[0])
```